# Converting Array of Strings to floats (?!?!)

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

["3.789,33", "2.702,17", "481,21", "1.149,44", "3.037,85", "44,24", "524,49", "1.378,42", "32,02"]

and I would like to convert it to an array of numbers/floats.

I tried .map(Number) and also parseInt() and parseFloat() but didn't seem to work out.
Can anybody help?

Comment: You need to get rid of the commas before `Number()` will work.

Comment: You have `,` in numbers after `.`  ?

Comment: What are the commas for?

Comment: @CodeManiac euro-style number formatting; `,` is the decimal "point"

Comment: @Pointy oh okay wasn't aware of that, but `3.789,33` this seems odd to me, it has both `.` and `,`

Comment: If you want floats, I suggest using `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt`... :)

Comment: . means thousands and the , is the decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `.` by `empty string` and `,` by `.` before parsing it to float

```js
let arr = ["3.789,33", "2.702,17", "481,21", "1.149,44", "3.037,85", "44,24", "524,49", "1.378,42", "32,02"]

let final = arr.map(v=> parseFloat(v.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.')))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks! This almost works. The only problem is that some numbers like 481,21 are converted into 48121.

Comment: @Jojo yeah misplaced replace, fixed !!!

Comment: Better `replace(/\./g, "")` as there could be multiple thousands seperators in a number.